# "who is not driving.", continuous verb or an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

> *passenger*  – a person **who is not driving**; the side of a car opposite the driver.  [Driving and Traffic](http://www.stickyball.net/esl-vocab.html?id=492)

In the above sentence, Is "(is) driving" continuous verb or an adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who is not driving?

The sentence is present continuous; the word driving is a present participle.

You cannot use the driving as an adjective on its owm; you use a noun after it.  For examples:

I passed the driving test.

He's the driving force behind the business.

You can also use the driving as a noun:

He has to do a lot of driving in his job.

Idon't like driving.

Comment: Thank you @Khan, I'm wondering, is it common to use present continuous with definitions?

Comment: @Shannak,  you can also use the present simple.  Passenger - a person who travels in a vehicle but isn't the driver of the vehicle.